# Почему нет общего доступа?

Tags: windows, сеть

> 1. Невозможно привязать сервер к транспорту ..., так как другой компьютер в сети имеет совпадающее имя.  Запуск сервера невозможен.
> 2. Ресурс общего доступа к файлам и принтерам ... доступен в сети, но не отвечает на попытки подключения.

Первую ошибку получаю после установления связи с сервером VPN Windows, на машине к которой пытаюсь получить общий доступ. Вторую ошибку получаю при диагностике ошибки подключения к машине.

К нужной мне машине я могу подключится по RDP, и получается открывать общие папки моего сервера VPN с неё, но наоборот это не работает. В сети нету компьютеров которые имеют одинаковые имена. В локальной сети всё работает, сеть частная, антивирус не блокирует, NB включен.

В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здравствуй,

Согласно вашему расшифровке код ошибки равен 720. Такое поведение может возникнуть, если ваш компьютер и сервер RAS не имеют общего протокола, или если RAS настроен неправильно. Или попытка подключения не удалась, потому что ваш компьютер и удаленный компьютер не смогли договориться о протоколе управления PPP.

Я бы предложил сначала переустановить протокол TCP / IP и отключить Ipv6 от использования (только для Ipv4) на клиентской стороне.

Если этот вопрос по-прежнему сохраняется, обратитесь к следующей ссылке для получения дополнительной информации, было упомянуто много предложений и практики.

PPTP VPN в Windows 7 - ошибка 720

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/eb37b71e-a021-47ee-896e-186cef55bf11/pptp-vpn-on-windows-7-error-720?forum=w7itpronetworking

С Уважением,

Comment: Почему я после перезагрузки моих клиентов могу получить общий доступ к их папкам? Если перезагружу свой компьютер - доступ пропадает. Если подключу клиента заново - кажется тоже пропадает